# Installed on external HDD, now need to get rid of extra boot options

Tags: boot

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my external hard drive, but now I have boot options I cannot delete! [image] My external drive is unplugged. How can I delete them?

Comment: One stayed and keeps repoping every boot times, the other one got deleted but now I can't even boot on my external drive!

Comment: Did you add an ESP - efi system partition on sdb? Normally when you disconnect a drive, the internal boot entries disappear. But since entries are on internal drive, I guess they do not. External drive can boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, but you would have to copy files from sda's ESP to have that work. Is that what you want? I normally copy /EFI/ubuntu on sda to sdb and then copy again to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to only have the boot option shown when the external drive is plugged in. It's either shown always or never, in which case you can't boot off of the external drive.